# Why can't I install any software any more with MSI installer (msiexec)

Tags: windows-xp, crash, windows-installer

I suddenly can't install any software.  I have admin rights on my machine but if I try to install anything that uses the windows installer I get this error:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions for whats getting corrupted here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try re-installing or upgrading your version of [MSI Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=5A58B56F-60B6-4412-95B9-54D056D6F9F4&displaylang=en).